# How to attach a html form to Django Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I do have a form in html and I want to post the data from this form to Django DB. Does there has anyways to do it or I must use the {{form.as_p}} inside the html?

The form inside the html:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
       <div class="row align-items-stretch mb-5">
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name"/>
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="mail" name="email"/>
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mb-md-0">
            <input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone"/>
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group form-group-textarea mb-md-0">
             <textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="content"></textarea>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
           </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
           <div id="success"></div>
               <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase" type="submit">發送</button>
           </div>
</form>
```

views.py. How do I connect the html form to forms.py?

```
def contact(request):

form = messageForm(request.POST or None)

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = messageForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return redirect('/#contact')
else:
    form = messageForm

context = {
    'form': form,
}
return render(request, 'contact.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class messageForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = message
    fields = ('name', 'mail', 'phone', 'content')
```

Comment: Also I want to figure it out how to design the form if it must use the {{form}} tag in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use built in forms. You can post data to DB from any form with the name attribute of fields. Add below codes in your project. Hope it will help.

models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):

    """your other fields"""
    objects = models.Manager()
```

views.py

```
def contact(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST["name"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        phone = request.POST["phone"]
        content = request.POST["content"]

        Message.objects.create(name = name, mail = email, phone = phone, content = content).save()

        return redirect('/#contact')

    else:
        return render(request, 'contact.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either render the entire form using the `{{ form }}` tag or you must control the individual elements with code like `{{ form.my_field_name }}` which you would probably render within your template's `<div></div>` elements.