# How to Submit a category form in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to submit a category form in Django,but it's not saving data in my Database table and it's redirecting me on create category page. I have already created a `forms.py` file, but that's not working properly, I am working with creating my custom HTML form, Please check my code and let me know where i am Mistaking, and how i can submit this form data in Database table.

Here are my Urls.py file...

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^category/create/$',views.add_cat, name="catadd"),
]
```

Here are my models.py file code...

```
class Category(models.Model):
  catType=models.IntegerField(default=None)
  cat_name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
  cat_slug=models.SlugField(max_length=225, unique=True)
  meta_title=models.CharField(max_length=225)
  meta_desc=models.CharField(max_length=285)
  meta_keyword=models.CharField(max_length=285)
  status=models.BooleanField()
  linkable=models.BooleanField()
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  def __str__(self):
     return self.cat_name
```

Here are my forms.py file...

```
from django import forms
from .models import Category

class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model=Category
      fields=('catType','cat_name','cat_slug','meta_title','meta_desc','meta_keyword','status','linkable')
```

Here are my views.py files..

```
def add_cat(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    form = CategoryForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cate = form.save(commit=False)
        cate.save()
        return redirect('dashboard/category')
else:
    form=CategoryForm()
return render(request, 'dashboard/category/createcat.html', {'form': form})
```

here are my createcat.html file..

```
<form class="form-horizontal m-bottom-30 catForm" id="wizard-arrow" method="POST" action="{% url 'dashboard:catadd' %}" novalidate="novalidate">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <ul class="list-steps">
                <li class="col-sm-4 step-item-arrow active">
                    <a href="#arrow-one" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-lock bg-primary"></i>
                        <span>Category Name Section</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-4 step-item-arrow">
                    <a href="#arrow-two" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-gear bg-primary"></i>
                        <span>Category Meta Section</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="col-sm-4 step-item-arrow">
                    <a href="#arrow-three" data-toggle="tab">
                        <i class="fa fa-paypal bg-primary"></i>
                        <span>Status &amp; Submit</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="tab-content col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="arrow-one">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Select Category<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <select class="form-control" name="country1">
                                  <option value="0">Project Category</option>
                                  <option value="1">Blog Category</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cat_name" class="control-label col-sm-3">Category Name<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cat_name" name="cat_name">
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cat_slug" class="control-label col-sm-3">Category Slug<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cat_slug" name="cat_slug">
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                    </div><!-- /.tab-pane -->

                    <div class="tab-pane" id="arrow-two">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="meta_title" class="control-label col-sm-3">Meta Title: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="meta_title" name="meta_title" placeholder="Category Meta Title">
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="meta_desc" class="control-label col-sm-3">Meta Description: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" maxlength="100" name="meta_desc" autocomplete="off" id="meta_desc" placeholder="Category Meta Description" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="meta_keyword" class="control-label col-sm-3">Meta Keywords: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" name="meta_keyword" id="meta_keyword" value="" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Enter Project Keywords">
                            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                        </div>
                        </div><!-- /.tab-pane -->

                        <div class="tab-pane" id="arrow-three">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="status">Category Status</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="status" style="width:100%">
                                      <option value="Active">Active</option>
                                      <option value="Inactive">Inactive</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="linkable">Is Linkable</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="linkable" style="width:100%">
                                      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                      <option value="No">No</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                    </div><!-- /.tab-content -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-warning-outline btn-prev">Previous Step</button>
                            </div><!-- /.col-sm-6 -->

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-info btn-next" name="Submit">Next Step</button>
                                <button type="button" id="catSubmit" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-finish none">Finish</button>
                            </div><!-- /.col-sm-6 -->
                        </div><!-- /.row -->
                    </div><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </form>
```

Comment: Check my this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61991218/how-to-attach-a-html-form-to-django-form/61992833#61992833) out. It might help to get data from custom form

Comment: i want to using this `import form` , i can do it using objests in `views`

Comment: could you please check where i am mistaking in my `views.py` file

Comment: You are supposed to use {{ form }} in your html file.